# how to get an image from a folder to get to render in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs, multer

i am making an e-commerce website. currently, we are uploading an image using multer and rest of the data is getting saved in mongodb. all the data is getting upload correctly but when I try to get image from folder/public/image  nothings work. any help would be appreciated.

this is my code for multer

```
app.post('/addProduct', function(req, res){    
upload(req,res,(err)=>{

            if(err){
                res.render('addproduct',{
                    mesg: err
                });
            }
                new product({
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                     image:req.body.image,
                     name: req.body.name,
                     price:  req.body.price,
                     description: req.body.description,
                     category: req.body.category,
                 }).save(function(err)
                 {
                     if(err){
                         console.log(err);
                         res.render('addProduct')
                     }else{
                     res.redirect('/products');
                 }
                 })
            });
        })
        //all function for uploading images and checking file
    //storage engine
    const storage= multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './Public/images/',
        filename: function(req, file, cb){
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
        }   
    });
    //upload method
    const upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('image');
};
```

This is code for getting a file from ./public/image folder

```
    <div class= "two row">   
                    <% products.forEach(product => { %>
                        <div class="column">

                                <img src="./Public/images/<%req.files[0].filename%>" class="cover-img">
                                <p><%= product.name %></p>
                                <h3>&dollar;<%= product.price %></h3>
                             <!---  <p><%= product.description %></p>-->
                        </div>
                   <% }); %>
```

addProduct.ejs code

```
<div class= "two row" onclick="">  
                <% products.forEach(product => { %>
                    <div class="column">
                        <img src="/images/<%req.files[0].filename%>" class="cover-img">
                            <p><%= product.name %></p>
                            <h3>&dollar;<%= product.price %></h3>
                         <a action="/products/productId"></a><button class="btn">Add to cart</button></a>
                         <!---  <p><%= product.description %></p>-->
                    </div>
               <% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to have `Public` prepended to the asset path. So your `<img>` src can just be:

```html
<img src="/images/<%req.files[0].filename%>" class="cover-img">
```

However, it's important that you have static assets set up for your Express application. [Follow the docs here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to see how that's done.

All you really need to do for that is to have:

```js
app.use(express.static('Public'))
```

somewhere at the top of your Express app.

Comment: hey i already have that in app.js. i just cant find a way to get around that. problem is still unsolved